# Cast HashMap in LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I'm getting the results from the database into a `List<Map<String, Object>>`. The problem the values are not in order, so I thought to cast in a LinkedHashMap, but I get this exception:

```
 javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class java.util.LinkedHashMap (java.util.HashMap and java.util.LinkedHashMap are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

The method is this:

```
protected EntityManager em;
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select * from City");
NativeQueryImpl nativeQuery = (NativeQueryImpl) q;
nativeQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> r = (List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>) nativeQuery.getResultList();
r.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Does anybody knows how can I print results in order?

Comment: Do you mean you want to print the list elements in order, or for each map you want to print the mappings (key-value pairs) in order, and if so, in which order? Or did you want both? Please give example of desired output and observed output.

Comment: You could write your own ```Comparator``` to order your list by ```Collections.sort(list, comparator)```, or you have to construct a new fat LinkedHashMap with respectation of unique keys.

Comment: do you mean to have the columns sorted or the whole list? (a cast does NOT change the runtime type of an instance - that is not possible, you need to create a new instance of different type)

Comment: For a sorted map fill the contents of your `HashMap` into a new `TreeMap`.

Comment: Please clarify what need to be sorted? If you want the list to be sorted, then use `ORDER BY` in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this class and call it instead of: `AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE`

```
public class MyTransformer extends AliasedTupleSubsetResultTransformer {

public static final MyTransformer INSTANCE = new MyTransformer();

/**
 * Disallow instantiation of AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.
 */
private MyTransformer() {
}

@Override
public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
    Map result = new LinkedHashMap<>(tuple.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < tuple.length; i++) {
        String alias = aliases[i];
        if (alias != null) {
            result.put(alias, tuple[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean isTransformedValueATupleElement(String[] aliases, int tupleLength) {
    return false;
}

/**
 * Serialization hook for ensuring singleton uniqueing.
 *
 * @return The singleton instance : {@link #INSTANCE}
 */
private Object readResolve() {
    return INSTANCE;
}
}
```